# How to refresh 2nd activity after intent from 1st activity

Tags: android

Hi I want to refresh the list after moving from 1st activity to 2nd activity. I have tried many other ways like recreate() but that is not working for me.

I have used Intent in my 1st activity and **onResume** on 2nd activity, which is not working for me.

1st activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SaleOrderDetails.this,SalesOrders.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

2nd activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    clearList();
    retrieveSalesOrder();
    super.onResume();
}

 public void clearList(){
    searchedSaleOrder.clear();
    saleOrderModelForDrafts.clear();
    saleOrderModelForConfirms.clear();
    saleOrderModelForCancels.clear();
    saleOrderModelForFullfilments.clear();
    readyForShippment.clear();
    readyToPickUp.clear();
}
```

Whenever we intent to the activity it should refresh.

Comment: please post your clearList(); function

Comment: In second activity are you using list?

Comment: Yes I am using ArrayList.

Comment: do you have a searchview ??

Comment: Yes I am also using search view.

Comment: are you using listview to show the list?

Comment: @AkshathaSrinivas I am using NonScrollListView

Comment: try `listview.notifyDatasetChanged()` to refresh the list.

Comment: @AkshathaSrinivas I am using NonScrollListView and it is not giving me notifyDatasetChanged() instead of that it is showing deferNotifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  clearList();
  retrieveSalesOrder();
}

 public void clearList(){
  searchedSaleOrder.clear();
  saleOrderModelForDrafts.clear();
  saleOrderModelForConfirms.clear();
  saleOrderModelForCancels.clear();
  saleOrderModelForFullfilments.clear();
  readyForShippment.clear();
  readyToPickUp.clear();
}
```

Use clearlist after super();

Comment: Not working even after doing this my list is not updating. But when I forcefully click that activity from nav drawer than it is updating

Comment: impossible that it will not work can you show whole activity code please

Comment: Where I can post it?